# Spring MVC ResponseEntity for image not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

In Spring MVC I'm trying to handle "image not found" case with appropriate response but no luck so far.
When catch block executes, in Chrome browser I get status "(failed) net::ERR_HTTP_RESSPONSE_CODE_FAILURE".
I guess it's because of empty byte array which cannot be an image.

What response should I return if I want to avoid some generic "no photo" image?

```
@GetMapping( path = "/{name}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> get( @PathVariable("name") String name ) {
    try {
        final MyImage img = this.imageService.getImage( name );
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType( MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE )
            .body( img.getBytes() );
    }
    catch( final ImageNotFoundException e ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>( new byte[] {}, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND );  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally handle all errors in a separate class, which is used to catch all errors and return proper status codes. Have a look at @ControllerAdvice-annotation. There are even more possibilities, how to deal with your exceptions.

In your case, you need to do remove the try catch block from your get-method and create a new class handling the ImageNotFoundException:

```
@GetMapping( path = "/{name}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> get( @PathVariable("name") String name ) {
    
        final MyImage img = this.imageService.getImage( name );
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType( MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE )
            .body( img.getBytes() );        
}
```

---

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultControllerResponseAdvise {
    @ExceptionHandler(ImageNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ProblemDetail> handleImageNotFoundException (ImageNotFoundException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried tihs, but I get the same result - not regular 404 but net::ERR_HTTP_RESSPONSE_CODE_FAILURE. Also tried to remove "produces"  but I get still the same.

Comment: The downside is that my log is getting filled with warnings: (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:207) [WARN ] Resolved [com.thevegcat.app.exception.VegImageNotFoundException: Photo 'c4c88cb1-2c75-42ab-8b5d-a3e7f1633ad2' not found]